# Cannot convert int to LPUNIT

Tags: c

I have an error with this codie.

'midiInGetID' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int *' to 'LPUINT'
What does `int *` and `LPUNIT` mean?

```
struct midi_in_list_node
{
    int midi_in_number;
    HMIDIIN midi_in;
    struct midi_in_list_node *next_midi_in_list_node;
};

struct midi_in_list_node *first_midi_in_list_node = NULL;

void CALLBACK midi_in_handler(HMIDIIN midi_in, UINT msg_type, DWORD user_data, DWORD midi_msg, DWORD param2)
{
    int midi_in_number;

    midiInGetID(midi_in, &midi_in_number);

    if (msg_type == MIM_DATA)
    {
```

After changing to UINT, I have other error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MIDI, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>MIDI.cpp
1>c:\users\wildfire\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\midi\midi\midi.cpp(103) : warning C4996: 'sscanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sscanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\stdio.h(324) : see declaration of 'sscanf'
1>Linking...
1>MIDI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInGetID@8 referenced in function "void __stdcall midi_in_handler(struct HMIDIIN__ *,unsigned int,unsigned long,unsigned long,unsigned long)" (?midi_in_handler@@YGXPAUHMIDIIN__@@IKKK@Z)
1>MIDI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInClose@4 referenced in function "int __stdcall control_handler(unsigned long)" (?control_handler@@YGHK@Z)
1>MIDI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInStop@4 referenced in function "int __stdcall control_handler(unsigned long)" (?control_handler@@YGHK@Z)
1>MIDI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInStart@4 referenced in function _main
1>MIDI.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__midiInOpen@20 referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\Wildfire\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MIDI\Debug\MIDI.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Wildfire\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\MIDI\MIDI\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>MIDI - 6 error(s), 1 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Please edit your post and fix the UNIT/UINT typo.  Also, are you stating you do not understand C pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your new problems, you need to link your project against the `winmm.lib` static library.  To do that, open up your **Project Settings** and go to **Linker** → **Input** → **Additional Dependencies** and add `winmm.lib` to that text box.

When you get errors like "Unresolved external symbol", that means you're not linking against the correct library.  To figure out what the correct library is, look at the documentation (e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd798455%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the documentation for `midiInGetID`).  Under the section **Requirements**, it lists `winmm.lib` as the required library.

Comment: I see, however, I wish to pass the output console to the

Comment: 127.0.0.1:9001 so that my xSocket (Java) can receive the data? Do you think I should program in Winsock? I not too familiar with Windows api

Answer (score 1):

`LPUNIT` is not the same as `LPUINT`.  `LPUINT` = **L** ong **P** ointer to **U** nsigned **int**.

Just do

```
UINT midi_in_number;
midiInGetID(midi_in, &midi_in_number);
```

Comment: I don't think the OP intended to write `LPUNIT`... It's just a typo.

Comment: Yap, typo error. And now I have other error, am I missing something?